# How can I make Intellij show relationship cardinality when I build ER diagram?

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, entity-relationship

I use standard IntelliJ ER diagram creator from persistence toolbox.
For now it shows relationships with just arrows:

[image]

I want it to show relationship cardinality between entities - like many-to-one, many-to-many, etc, something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this with IntelliJ? Should I use some plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same. Then I saw an option in the contextual menu:

[image: Show edge labels options at the bottom of IntelliJ's contextual menu]

At first the diagram looked odd, bout it's because it's using calculations previous to the labels, so you have to change the layout and get back and it will calculate properly the space for showing the cardinality.

Comment: This option no longer exists. how do i show cardinalities in datagrip visual diagram?